Open Set based on Function Image in Order Topology
I was reading through this stackexchange post, and the user Pete L. Clark stated that, given a continuous function $f:X\to X$, for $X$ being completely linearly ordered with the order topology, the sets $\{x\in X\mid f(x) < x\}$ and $\{x \in X \mid f(x) > x\}$ are open. I am completely at a loss for how to prove this.
For a bit of context on my background, I am a novice self-studying topology from Munkres' Second Edition. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

One nice way to try to prove this is to try to prove that ${(x, y) \mid x < y}$ is an open subset of $X \times X$ given the product topology. Do you see why that's true and how you can use it?

@IzaakvanDongen Do I represent the image of $f$ as ${(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X}$, then use the first projection?

Proving using the product $X \times X$ is of course a great approach, but you don't have to do it that way. We show that the first set is open via a direct proof; the approach for the second is basically the same.
Denote $A = \{ x \in X | f (x) < x \}$, and let $a \in A$ be arbitrary. We are looking for an open set $U$ containing $a$ such that $U \subseteq A$. We have by hypothesis that $f (a) < a$. Consider the subbasis element $(\leftarrow, a) \subseteq X$. Since $f$ is continuous, the pre-image of this set, call it $B = f^{-1} ((\leftarrow, a))$, is open in $X$ and contains $a$. The set $U = B \cap (f (a), \rightarrow)$, being the intersection of two open sets, is open; note that it too contains $a$. We claim that $U \subseteq A$. Let $y \in U$ be arbitrary. We have that $f (a) < y$, and $y \in B \implies f (y) < a$. These clearly imply $f (y) < y$, so that $y \in A$, as desired.

I don't quite understand. We have $B={x\in X \mid f(x) < a}$ and $U={x \in X \mid f(x)<a} \cap {x \in X \mid f(a) < x} = {x \in X \mid f(x) < a \wedge f(a) < x }$, so there is no way that $a \in U$. Am I misunderstanding?

Yes, in fact $a \in U$. First, we have $a \in A \implies f (a) < a$. Then clearly this means $a \in { x \in X | f (x) < a }$. Also, it means that $a \in { x \in X | f (a) < x }$.

Ah I see. I messed up the inequalities in my head, though not in writing. Thank you for your help, and I'll mark your answer as accepted.
